# Under what category should myosin come?

Tags: cell-biology

Are myosin microfilaments or intermediate filaments? Or are they simply motor proteins? Under which category should I put them? I am highly confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myosin are motor proteins. Microfilaments (AKA actin filaments) are the tracks for Myosin. Filaments of different sizes are the structural components of cells, giving them their shape, rigidity, etc., as well as providing an intracellular network for transport. Myosin walk along these filaments.

In myocytes (muscle cells), myosin pulls actin filaments towards one another.

[image: Myosin and actin filaments]

Picture from here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9961/

Comment: but in muscle cells?

Comment: @JM97 Please see edit.